# Solr JQuery autocomplete doesn't autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, solr

I'm trying to implement an HTML autocomplete form with Solr and JQuery UI.

Solr's server log the query and Firebug confirm that I get a json array :

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":3,"params":{"fl":"defaultCommonNameString","q":"defaultCommonName:angle","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":42,"start":0,"docs":[{"defaultCommonNameString":["angle"]},{"defaultCommonNameString":["reporter un angle"]},{"defaultCommonNameString":["formule pour un angle"]},{"defaultCommonNameString":["angle droit"]},{"defaultCommonNameString":["angle au centre"]}, ...]}}}
```

But this code doesn't display the response :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demos.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#autosearch").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/solr/select",
            data: { 
                q: "defaultCommonName:"+request.term,
        wt:"json",
        fl: "defaultCommonNameString",
             }, 
             dataType: "json",
             type: "GET",

             success: function( data ) {
                data=parse();
                function parse(){
                var parsedQueries=[];
                    for(var i=0;i<data.response.docs.length;i++){
                        parsedQueries[i]=data.response.docs[i].Query;
                    }
                    return parsedQueries;
                }

                response($.map(data.response.docs, function( item ) { 
                    return { 
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }; 
            }));
            }
          }); 
         },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<label for="autosearch">Search Here :  </label>
<input id="autosearch"/>
</body>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: what does data.response.docs[i].Query refer to? Should it be instead data.response.docs[i].defaultCommonNameString ?

Comment: yes it's data.response.docs[i].defaultCommonNameString but it doesn't change the result :-(

Comment: try this: dataType: "jsonp"; also minLength: 2 might be more efficient, but that depends on your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using above code its working fine but server ip and port is open directly on page source is there any way to encrypt this information.

Comment: You can use apache proxy to redirect the request.

Then simply use the current url to redirect :
var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
...
$. ajax ({
         url: url + '/solr/.../select',
         ...

Answer (score 6):

Many thanks D_K, that's work fine !!!

The code :

```
$(function() {
    $("#autosearch").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/solr/select",
            data: { 
                q: "defaultCommonName:"+request.term,
                fl: "defaultCommonNameString",
                wt: 'json',
             }, 
             dataType: "jsonp",
             jsonp: 'json.wrf',

             success: function( data ) {
                response($.map(data.response.docs, function( item ) { 
                    return { 
                        label: item.defaultCommonNameString,
                        value: item.defaultCommonNameString,
                    }; 
            }));
            }
          }); 
         },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });
```